# How to get my files from my encrypted home folder on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: ubuntu, encryption

Last night there was a power outage and now my computer will not boot up. After pushing the power button and seeing the BIOS I only see a black screen with a white cursor at the top left of the screen. I plugged in an external hard drive and put in my live CD hoping I could use the live CD to copy my files from my home folder to my external drive. But when I opened the home folder each containing folder says I do not have access to them and they are all empty. I assume this is because I encrypted my home folder when I first installed Ubuntu. How can I get my files back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to open a terminal.

`sudo passwd root`

Then

`su`

You are root now.

You can use `chmod 755` to modify the permission.

Comment: Okay I've followed the first part have succesfully became root, but I don't know how to do the chmod 666

Comment: chmod -R 666 /some/folder

Comment: If you don't know the path of the folder, drag a file into the terminal, you will see it.

Comment: okay I did that to my pictures folder, it made me put in sudo chmod -R 666 though. However it only fixed the perisions on first folder itself, all other files and folders with in are still unaccessable. Is there a way to do every thing? Others I'm going to be here for LONG time lol

Comment: If you pictures folder is /xxx/home/yourname/Pictures/ ,you can use `chmod -R 666 '/xxx/home/yourname/'` to change more files.

Comment: I just did that to the main home folder, but alot of folders permisions and all files that I've looked at still show 000 as their permisions and I can't move them.

Comment: Do the same operation for any folder you want.

Comment: I've done it on ever folder, but there contents remain empty, Right click on a folder still shows that it is gigabytes in size and they still show as having 000 permisions  but there is nothing with in, not even when I show hidden files. *SIGH* I'm guessing, maybe the files have become corrupted.

Comment: The `-R` operation makes setting permissions recursively. I don't think changing permissions can corrupt a file. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740152/how-to-set-chmod-for-a-folder-and-all-of-its-subfolders-and-files-in-linux-ubunt

Comment: No I mean they poweroutage may have currpoted some stuff. Seeing as also the computer wouldn't even turn on either. I don't guess there is anything I can do now. Thank you very much though, you was very helpfull :D

Comment: See `lost+found` folder, and check whether you can save something. I don't know how it woks though.

Comment: WAIT WAIT! I rebooted the computer and did everything you said but I used 775 instead of 666, worked perfectly, all of my files are now safe and copying to my external drive. Thank you very much :D *edit* that Thank you sounded sarcastic, it wasn't meant to be though really thanks :D

Comment: I have modified it. I usually do 777 instead 666, and think 666 may be enough to copy the files. I am mistaken.